# What is the file contents.css in CKeditor?

Tags: ckeditor

CKeditor's installation instructions tell me to just unzip the whole distribution file on my webserver's production directory. But it is full of files I definitely don't want there, like source code, examples, and even server-side code in PHP. I got rid of most of these files but there is one I'm not sure about: contents.css.

I can see this file uses a lot of styles I definitely don't want to see in my site. My question is:

Is contents.css required by CKeditor, or used by default? Do I even need this file on my production site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it depends on what you're using in CKeditor, or what you *plan* to use later. Personally, I'd suggest renaming the file (something like) `contents.css.old` and creating a new `contents.css` file, copy across all the styles that you think you'll need and then destruct-test your implementation of CKeditor, to assess whether you've got all the styles that you need.

Add to, or remove from, that file to get your finished version and then use that one. I'd strongly advise keeping the original version around though, for future development purposes.

To your specific questions, though:

> Is `contents.css` required by CKeditor, or used by default?

I *believe* so.

> Do I even need this file on my production site?

Not so far as I know, its absence will likely cause things to look a little less-pretty, though, until you apply your own styles.

As suggested, above, though, I'd rename the original and then create your *own* stylesheet with the same name, it's rather easier than going through all the various js files looking for, and changing as appropriate, references to `contents.css`.

Comment: Thank you! What I failed to realize is that CKeditor is hosted inside an iframe, so those styles won't interfere with my site's. It is clear now.